# How to get all indices for values of one array which are contained in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexof

Lets say we have two simple 1d numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6]) 
b = np.array([1, 5, 7])
```

Now what I want is to get all possible indices where each value from array `b` is contained in array `a`.

We could do e.g. the following:

```
idx = np.where(np.any(a.reshape((-1, 1))==b, axis=1))[0]
```

Where `idx` is `array([0, 1, 3, 4, 8])` (which is what I actually want).

Now I am really curious if there is already a similar function for this problem in numpy or any other library (where I believe that there already exist one). Otherwise I will stick with the working approach now.

Comment: use `np.where(np.in1d(a, b))[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `np.isin`/`np.in1d` -

```
np.flatnonzero(np.isin(a,b))
# or np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(a,b))
```

Might be more performant with `np.searchsorted` for sorted `b` -

```
sidx = np.searchsorted(b,a)
sidx[sidx==len(b)] = len(b)-1
out = np.flatnonzero(b[sidx]==a)
```

If `b` is not sorted, sort it and then use it instead of `b`.

Comment: So there does not exist a single function for this?

Comment: @PiMathCLanguage Nope. Playing code-golf or something? :)

Comment: Could be useful/used for code-golf. But I was more curious and also wanted to have a more performant code for my real problem too.

Comment: @PiMathCLanguage Length of code isn't necessarily related to the performance. Play around with NumPy tools and funcs and see which one works best for you.

Comment: Your second example is really much faster. I have also made a test script for this 3 approaches. You can find it [here](https://github.com/hearues-zueke-github/python_programs/blob/master/test_programs/performance_tests.py). Your more performant code is ~2 times faster than your first suggestion.